# Why 'git config --list' showing me two email addresses with one username?

Tags: git, github

I am trying to change my git configuration in my Mac from terminal because I got a new job. I have set the username, email and password globally by these commands:

```
git config --global user.name "My Username"
git config --global user.email "My Email"
git config --global user.password "My Password"
```

But when I check the configuration by `git config --list` in the terminal I see two email addresses with one username. One email That I have just set, and another one is my previous company email. How can I completely remove the previous company email?

Comment: Note that no standard Git program looks for a `user.password` setting. You can set anything you like that nobody looks for, of course, e.g., `git config --global leeloo.dallas.multipass true`. Irrelevant, unused configuration entries are mostly harmless. But your global `.gitconfig` is generally readable by anyone with access to your machine, so putting passwords in it is probably not wise.

Answer (score 8):

You probably have two different settings in two different config files.  You can use `git config --list --show-origin` to show which file each setting comes from, and then edit the file containing the value you don't want.